# Prove that $S\circ T$ and $T\circ S$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me with this question: Let $S$ and $T$ be linear operator on the same finite dimensional vector space. Suppose $S$ is invertible. Prove that $S\circ T$ and $T\circ S$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

I was told to use 2 similar square matrices to prove but i got stuck halfway.

Comment: This holds even if $S$ and $T$ are not invertible, by the way.

Comment: @Potato, and the usual proof requires a reduction to the case when $S$ is invertible http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices

Comment: @AndreasCaranti We're pleased to see that $\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B)=\det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C)$ through the row reduction of the block matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 4):

This is just because the two operators are conjugate
$$
T S = S^ {-1} (S T) S,
$$
and thus 
\begin{align}
\det(TS - \lambda I)
&=
\det(S^ {-1} (S T) S - \lambda I)
\\&= 
\det(S^ {-1} (S T - \lambda I) S)
\\&=
\det(S^ {-1}) \det (S T - \lambda I) \det(S)
\\&=
\det(ST - \lambda I).
\end{align}

Comment: oh thanks. but $s^{-1}$$s$=1 which means TS=ST? but its composite functions, are they still equal?

Comment: @LeongLyn, please keep in mind that multiplication (composition) of operators is non-commutative in general! Just consider $S = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $T=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: I'm a yr 1 math major. Could u explain to me why TS=$S^{−1}$ (ST)S. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Start with $S^{-1}(S T)S$. Use associativity to rewrite as $(S^{-1}S) TS$. By definition of inverse $S^{-1}S = I$, the identity matrix, so $S^{-1}(S T)S = (S^{-1}S) TS = I T S = TS$.

Comment: can explain how to get from first line to second line of the determinant working?

Comment: @LeongLyn, just distribute twice to find $S^ {-1} (S T - \lambda I) S = (S^ {-1} S T - S^ {-1} \lambda I) S = S^ {-1} S T S - S^ {-1} \lambda I S = TS - \lambda I$.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$TS=S^{-1}\left(ST\right) S\Longrightarrow TS\sim ST$$